# Why is syntax highlighting not working

Tags: support

I have added the language tag like so --

`<!-- language: js -->`

But for some reason syntax highlighting still doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the answer I am talking about --
[Twilio SRV lookup while forwarding to SIP URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160769//48162369#48162369)

Comment: That's not the correct syntax. It's "javascript" to have it look up the JavaScript tag's highlighting option, or "lang-js" to just explicitly specify the JavaScript highlighter. Your syntax attempts to look up the tag "js" which doesn't exist, so no highlighting is applied at all.